# Is there a problem while creating setUp() function in my Unit test cases?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am writing unit test cases for my app.py file. I have created a setUp() function in my test file but the moment I execute any test case, it throws an error like

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-6.1.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /home/curiousguy/PycharmProjects/leadgen/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/curiousguy/PycharmProjects/leadgen/tests
plugins: cov-2.10.1
collecting ... ENV :None

test_app.py:None (test_app.py)
test_app.py:5: in <module>
    from app import app
../app.py:7: in <module>
    from appli import appli
../appli.py:6: in <module>
    appli = create_app(db, config_name)
../app_setup.py:21: in create_app
    leadgen_app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
E   KeyError: None
collected 0 items / 1 error

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________________________ ERROR collecting test_app.py _________________________
test_app.py:5: in <module>
    from app import app
../app.py:7: in <module>
    from appli import appli
../appli.py:6: in <module>
    appli = create_app(db, config_name)
../app_setup.py:21: in create_app
    leadgen_app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
E   KeyError: None
```

The test file is:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
# from appli import appli
from app import app
#import app


class MyApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.testing = True
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_settings_passed(self):
        response = self.client.get('/settings', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        with pytest.raises(AssertionError) as wt:
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

Since the errors are pointing to different files I am adding those files as well.
app.py

```
import functools
import pickle
from flask import (redirect,  render_template, request, Response, session, url_for)
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, current_user
from flask_admin import Admin
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, SIMPLE
from appli import appli
import datetime
from modules.controller import application
from modules.users_view import MyAdminIndexView, UsersView
from database.db_model import (Companies, Users, Leads, db)

###########################################################
#                    Init section                         #
###########################################################


app = appli

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.init_app(app)

server = Server(app.config['LDAP_SERVER'],
                port=app.config['LDAP_PORT'], get_info=ALL)

server_tor = Server(app.config['LDAP_SERVER_TOR'],
                    port=app.config['LDAP_PORT'], get_info=ALL)

admin = Admin(app, name='LEADGEN Admin', index_view=MyAdminIndexView(), base_template='master.html')
admin.add_view(UsersView(Users, db.session))

application_inst = application("Lead Generator")
#rest of code
```

appli.py

```
import os
from app_setup import create_app
from database.db_model import db

config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')
appli = create_app(db, config_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appli.run()
```

app_Setup.py

```
def create_app(db,config_name):
    leadgen_app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    # config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV', 'default')
    print('ENV :' + str(config_name))
    # leadgen_app.config.from_object(eval(settings[config_name]))
    leadgen_app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    leadgen_app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg', silent=True)

    # Configure logging
    leadgen_app.logger.setLevel(leadgen_app.config['LOGGING_LEVEL'])
    handler = logging.FileHandler(leadgen_app.config['LOGGING_LOCATION'])
    handler.setLevel(leadgen_app.config['LOGGING_LEVEL'])
    formatter = logging.Formatter(leadgen_app.config['LOGGING_FORMAT'])
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    leadgen_app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    leadgen_app.logger.propagate = 0

    # Configure sqlalchemy
    leadgen_app.app_context().push()
    db.init_app(leadgen_app)
    # with leadgen_app.app_context():
    #     db.create_all()

    from leads.leads_bp import leads_bp
    from process.process_bp import process_bp
    from CAAPI.caapi_bp import caAPI_bp
    leadgen_app.register_blueprint(leads_bp)
    leadgen_app.register_blueprint(process_bp)
    leadgen_app.register_blueprint(caAPI_bp)
    return leadgen_app
```

Where am I making a mistake to run my test case successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` is caused by `app_config[config_name]`.

`config_name` comes from `config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')`.

`getenv` defaults to `None` when no value is set, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv

This means you have to set the environment variable in order to make tests pass.

You could also debug your application with `pdb` - I gave a lightning talk how to debug a Flask application...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxkco-gS4S8&ab_channel=PythonIreland

Comment: Hi, checked your answer a few moments back, I am able to solve it. Please check my answer

Comment: Obviously, there are more ways to solve a problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out an answer to this. here is what I did.
I made changes to my setUp() function in my testcase file

```
 def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(db)
        self.client = self.app.test_client(self)

        with self.app.app_context():
            # create all tables
            db.create_all()
```

and then I imported `from app_setup import create_app` in my testcase file. And finally I made changes in app_setup.py in function

```
def create_app(db, config_name='default')
```

And my testcases are now running.